# How can i let the user choose if they are a teacher or admin?

Tags: c++, while-loop, switch-statement

im very new to OOP, and im trying to create a menu for users to click on choose if they are a teacher or an admin

Hi there, I'm having a bit of trouble creating a menu for employees. It seems like a great idea, though. Could you help me out?

The code below:

```
#include "Employee.h"

int main() {
  Employee emp;
  char Select = '0';
  string confirm;

  emp->Initialize();

  while (Select != '8') {
    cout << "1. Administrator" << endl;
    cout << "2. Teacher" << endl;
    cout << "3. Add Employee" << endl;
    cout << "4. Update Employee" << endl;
    cout << "5. Delete Employee" << endl;
    cout << "6. Display an Employee" << endl;
    cout << "7. Calculate Possible Salary" << endl;
    cout << "8. Exit Program" << endl;
    cin >> Select;

    switch (Select) {
      {
        cout << "Are you an Administrator or Teacher" << endl;
      case 'A':
        emp->Administrator();
        break;

      case 'B':
        emp->Teacher();
      }

      cout << "Press Y or y to continue:";
      cin >> confirm;

      while (confirm == "Y" || confirm == "Y")
        ;
      { return 0; }

      cout << "File initialized successfully!" << endl;
      break;

    case '2':
      emp->AddEmployee();
      cout << "Employee added successfully!" << endl;
      break;

    case '3':
      emp->UpdateEmployee();
      cout << "Employee updated successfully!" << endl;
      break;

    case '4':
      emp->DeleteEmployee();
      cout << "Employee deleted successfully!" << endl;
      break;

    case '5':
      emp->DisplayEmployee();
      break;

    case '6':
      emp->CalculateSalary();
      break;

    default:
      cout << "Invalid Menu Option" << endl;
      break;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

So if the user chooses option 1 (by typing "1" into the console), it will execute Administrator. If the user chooses option 2, it will show Teacher.

Comment: Don't tag C++ code with the very distinguish language C.

Comment: Does the compiler not warn you about unreachable code after `{ return 0; }`?

Comment: Nope, doesn't say unreachable code. it just doesn't pick up the other codes that are passing through

Comment: What exactly is the "bit of trouble"? What are the symptoms? What did you observe? If the "trouble" is not an error when compiling, what did you expect to observe?

Comment: Your code should demonstrate the "trouble", not "a menu for users to [do whatever]". The key phrase to keep in mind is [mre]. If the trouble is with the menu, focus on the menu and remove `emp` from example. If the trouble can be reproduced without the menu, then do that. (Note: the commands `Employee emp; emp->Administrator(); emp->AddEmployee(); }` can be run without the menu.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read this code to yourself

```
cout << "1. Administrator" << endl;
cout << "2. Teacher" << endl;
cout << "3. Add Employee" << endl;
cout << "4. Update Employee" << endl;
cout << "5. Delete Employee" << endl;
cout << "6. Display an Employee" << endl;
cout << "7. Calculate Possible Salary" << endl;
cout << "8. Exit Program" << endl;
cin >> Select;

switch (Select) {
  {
    cout << "Are you an Administrator or Teacher" << endl;
  case 'A':
    emp->Administrator();
    break;

  case 'B':
    emp->Teacher();
  }
```

promtp the user to enter 1 or 2.

then ask a question  with no new input

then look to see if they pressed A or B.

I think you mean

```
cout << "1. Administrator" << endl;
cout << "2. Teacher" << endl;
cout << "3. Add Employee" << endl;
cout << "4. Update Employee" << endl;
cout << "5. Delete Employee" << endl;
cout << "6. Display an Employee" << endl;
cout << "7. Calculate Possible Salary" << endl;
cout << "8. Exit Program" << endl;
cin >> Select;

switch (Select) {
  {
  case '1':
    emp->Administrator();
    break;

  case '2':
    emp->Teacher();
  }
```

Comment: I'm really sorry for how worded it and bring it across, I'm very new but this is what i was aiming for thanks very much.